# ShowDialog Widget isn't return on (.CatchError)

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, flutter-widget

I am creating a simple Shop app where I implement logic of CircularProgressIndicator() When user add new product. And beside that to show AlertDialog When some error occurred. But the problem is Whenever I pressed Okay button on AlertDialog instead of going back to Products page the CircularProgressIndicator() keeps spinning.

Here is My code:

```
    class EditProductScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routname = '/edit-product-screen';
  const EditProductScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<EditProductScreen> createState() => _EditProductScreenState();
}

class _EditProductScreenState extends State<EditProductScreen> {
  final _priceFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _descriptionFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _imageUrlController = TextEditingController();
  final _imageUrlFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _form = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var _editedProduct = Product(
    id: null,
    title: '',
    price: 0,
    description: '',
    imageUrl: '',
  );
  var _initValues = {
    'title': '',
    'description': '',
    'price': '',
    'imageUrl': '',
  };
  var _isInit = true;
  var _isLoading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _imageUrlFocusNode.addListener(_updateImageUrl);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_isInit) {
      final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;
      // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
      if (productId != null) {
        _editedProduct = Provider.of<ProductsProvider>(context, listen: false)
            .findById(productId as String);
        _initValues = {
          'title': _editedProduct.title,
          'description': _editedProduct.description,
          'price': _editedProduct.price.toString(),
          // 'imageUrl': _editedProduct.imageUrl,
          'imageUrl': '',
        };
        _imageUrlController.text = _editedProduct.imageUrl;
      }
    }
    _isInit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _imageUrlFocusNode.removeListener(_updateImageUrl);
    _priceFocusNode.dispose();
    _descriptionFocusNode.dispose();
    _imageUrlController.dispose();
    _imageUrlFocusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _updateImageUrl() {
    if (!_imageUrlFocusNode.hasFocus) {
      if ((!_imageUrlController.text.startsWith('http') &&
              !_imageUrlController.text.startsWith('https')) ||
          (!_imageUrlController.text.endsWith('.png') &&
              !_imageUrlController.text.endsWith('.jpg') &&
              !_imageUrlController.text.endsWith('.jpeg'))) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  void _saveForm() {
    final isValid = _form.currentState!.validate();
    if (!isValid) {
      return;
    }
    _form.currentState!.save();
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
    if (_editedProduct.id != null) {
      Provider.of<ProductsProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .updateProduct(_editedProduct.id!, _editedProduct);
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    } else {
      Provider.of<ProductsProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .addProduct(_editedProduct)
          .catchError((onError) {
        return showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
            title: const Text("An Error Occourrd"),
            content: const Text("Something Went Wrong"),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
                },
                child: const Text("Okay"),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      }).then((_) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Edit Product'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.save),
            onPressed: _saveForm,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: _isLoading
          ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Form(
                key: _form,
                child: ListView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TextFormField(
                      initialValue: _initValues['title'],
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Title'),
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                      onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_priceFocusNode);
                      },
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value!.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please Enter a Title';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      onSaved: (value) {
                        _editedProduct = Product(
                            title: value.toString(),
                            price: _editedProduct.price,
                            description: _editedProduct.description,
                            imageUrl: _editedProduct.imageUrl,
                            id: _editedProduct.id,
                            isFav: _editedProduct.isFav);
                      },
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      initialValue: _initValues['price'],
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Price'),
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      focusNode: _priceFocusNode,
                      onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                        FocusScope.of(context)
                            .requestFocus(_descriptionFocusNode);
                      },
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value!.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter a price.';
                        }
                        if (double.tryParse(value) == null) {
                          return 'Please enter a valid number.';
                        }
                        if (double.parse(value) <= 0) {
                          return 'Please enter a number greater than zero.';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      onSaved: (value) {
                        _editedProduct = Product(
                            title: _editedProduct.title,
                            price: int.parse(value.toString()),
                            description: _editedProduct.description,
                            imageUrl: _editedProduct.imageUrl,
                            id: _editedProduct.id,
                            isFav: _editedProduct.isFav);
                      },
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      initialValue: _initValues['description'],
                      decoration:
                          const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Description'),
                      maxLines: 3,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                      focusNode: _descriptionFocusNode,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value!.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter a description.';
                        }
                        if (value.length < 10) {
                          return 'Should be at least 10 characters long.';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      onSaved: (value) {
                        _editedProduct = Product(
                          title: _editedProduct.title,
                          price: _editedProduct.price,
                          description: value.toString(),
                          imageUrl: _editedProduct.imageUrl,
                          id: _editedProduct.id,
                          isFav: _editedProduct.isFav,
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                    Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          width: 100,
                          height: 100,
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 8,
                            right: 10,
                          ),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(
                              width: 1,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: _imageUrlController.text.isEmpty
                              ? const Text('Enter a URL')
                              : FittedBox(
                                  child: Image.network(
                                    _imageUrlController.text,
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  ),
                                ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextFormField(
                            decoration:
                                const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Image URL'),
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
                            textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                            controller: _imageUrlController,
                            focusNode: _imageUrlFocusNode,
                            onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                              _saveForm();
                            },
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value!.isEmpty) {
                                return 'Please enter an image URL.';
                              }
                              if (!value.startsWith('http') &&
                                  !value.startsWith('https')) {
                                return 'Please enter a valid URL.';
                              }
                              if (!value.endsWith('.png') &&
                                  !value.endsWith('.jpg') &&
                                  !value.endsWith('.jpeg')) {
                                return 'Please enter a valid image URL.';
                              }
                              return null;
                            },
                            onSaved: (value) {
                              _editedProduct = Product(
                                title: _editedProduct.title,
                                price: _editedProduct.price,
                                description: _editedProduct.description,
                                imageUrl: value.toString(),
                                id: _editedProduct.id,
                                isFav: _editedProduct.isFav,
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is My Product Provider Class Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

import './product.dart';

class ProductsProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  // ignore: prefer_final_fields
  List<Product> _items = [
    Product(
      id: 'p1',
      title: 'Red Shirt',
      description: 'A red shirt - it is pretty red!',
      price: 29,
      imageUrl:
          'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/02/22/17/red-t-shirt-1710578_1280.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p2',
      title: 'Trousers',
      description: 'A nice pair of trousers.',
      price: 59,
      imageUrl:
          'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg/512px-Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p3',
      title: 'Yellow Scarf',
      description: 'Warm and cozy - exactly what you need for the winter.',
      price: 19,
      imageUrl:
          'https://live.staticflickr.com/4043/4438260868_cc79b3369d_z.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p4',
      title: 'A Pan',
      description: 'Prepare any meal you want.',
      price: 49,
      imageUrl:
          'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/14/Cast-Iron-Pan.jpg/1024px-Cast-Iron-Pan.jpg',
    ),
  ];

  List<Product> get items {
    // if (_showFavoritesOnly) {
    //   return _items.where((prodItem) => prodItem.isFavorite).toList();
    // }
    return [..._items];
  }

  List<Product> get favoriteItems {
    return _items.where((prodItem) => prodItem.isFav).toList();
  }

  Product findById(String id) {
    return _items.firstWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
  }

  void showFavoritesOnly() {
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void showAll() {
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> addProduct(Product product) {
    return http
        .post(
      Uri.parse(
          'https://example.com/products.json'),
      body: json.encode(
        {
          'title': product.title,
          'description': product.description,
          'price': product.price,
          'imageUrl': product.imageUrl,
          'isFav': product.isFav,
        },
      ),
    )
        .then((rresponce) {
      final newProduct = Product(
        title: product.title,
        description: product.description,
        price: product.price,
        imageUrl: product.imageUrl,
        id: json.decode(rresponce.body)['name'],
      );
      _items.add(newProduct);
      // _items.insert(0, newProduct); // at the start of the list
      notifyListeners();
    }).catchError((onError) {
      throw onError;
    });
  }

  void updateProduct(String id, Product newProduct) {
    final prodIndex = _items.indexWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
    if (prodIndex >= 0) {
      _items[prodIndex] = newProduct;
      notifyListeners();
    } else {}
  }

  void deleteProduct(String id) {
    _items.removeWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Navigator.of(ctx).pop();` will be used to close the dialog, in order to go back, you need to call again `Navigator.of(context).pop();`

try this way

```dart
void _saveForm() async {
  final isValid = _form.currentState!.validate();
  if (!isValid) {
    return;
  }
  _form.currentState!.save();
  setState(() {
    _isLoading = true;
  });
  // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
  if (_editedProduct.id != null) {
    Provider.of<ProductsProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .updateProduct(_editedProduct.id!, _editedProduct);
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  } else {
    try {
      await Provider.of<ProductsProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .addProduct(_editedProduct);

      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
      if (mounted) {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
          title: const Text("An Error Occourrd"),
          content: const Text("Something Went Wrong"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
              },
              child: const Text("Okay"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
      print("tada");
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });

      if (mounted) {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Alright, but Now if I tried to Add product which will not produce error is making CircularProgressIndicator() keeps spinning and not going back to product page
It is Pushing product on the server but not showing in app

Comment: Do you mean, even if it fails to upload the product , still shows on app?

Comment: No,
First Error Was if  it fails to upload the product it will show the alertDialog and after pressing the okay button the it will go back to product page without uploading product, It is solved now.

But the Problem with this now is If the product is uploaded successfully it should have to go back to product page after uploading but the error am facing is Product is uploaded but it is not going back to product page but keep showing spinner

Comment: I think, you can add `Navigator.pop` end of the try bloc. try update snippet

Answer (score 0):

The culprit here is a type inference mismatch, and you should have an error in your console:

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s) (onError): The error handler of Future.catchError must return a value of the future's type
```

In your provider, the `catchError` returns a `Future<Null>`

```dart
Future<void> addProduct(Product value) {
    var product = value;
    final url = Uri.parse('${Config.firebaseUrl}/products');
    return http
        .post(url, body: ...)
        .then((response) { // handle response }) // here returns nothing
        .catchError((error) {throw error}); // so here returns Future<Null>
  }
```

You can see it with Android Studio:
[image: android studio type inference]

When in your Widget, the `showDialog` returns a `Future<void>`.

This is not seen at compile time, I suspect because of dynamic type inference, but at runtime, you have:

```dart
Provider.of<ProductsProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .addProduct(_editedProduct) // Future<Null>
          .catchError((onError) {
            return showDialog(...);
          })                         // Future<void>
          .then((_) { ... });
```

Thus the runtime error message.

To fix the error, simply delete the `catchError` block from your `addProduct` function. The error will still be thrown, but you will not have the type overwrite of `catchError` from `Future<void>` to `Future<null>` :

```dart
Future<void> addProduct(Product value) {
    var product = value;
    final url = Uri.parse('${Config.firebaseUrl}/products');
    return http
        .post(url, body: ...)
        .then((response) { // handle response }); // removed catchError
  }
```